# Solving NQueens problem using backtracking algorithm in java

Tags: java, backtracking, n-queens

I started to learn about backtracking algorithm and totally digest the concept .
so I tried to solve NQueen problem Myself but failed ,
here is the code

underAttack(i,j) is to check if there is another queen on the same diagonal or in the same column  .

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class NQueenProblem {

    static int n;
    static int[][] a;

    public static boolean checkDiagonal(int r, int c) {

        int sum = r + c;
        int diff = Math.abs(r - c);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            if (r != i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    if (c != j) {
                        int sumD = i + j;
                        int diffD = Math.abs(i - j);
                        if (sum == sumD || sum == diffD || diff == sumD || diff == diffD) {
                            if (a[i][j] ==1)
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean checkColumn(int ii, int j) {

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (a[i][j] == 1 && i != ii) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

    public static boolean underAttack(int i, int j) {
        return checkDiagonal(i, j) || checkColumn(i, j);
    }

    public static void backtrack(int row) {
        if (row == n)
            return;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

            if (underAttack(row, j)) {
                continue;
            }
            a[row][j] = 1;
            backtrack(++row);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        n = 4;
        a = new int[n][n];
        backtrack(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a[i]));
        }
    }

}
```

I have made it size of 4 , and the output was like this

```
[1, 0, 0, 0]  
[0, 0, 1, 0]  
[0, 0, 0, 0]  
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

so can anyone tell me where the problem is .

Comment: Well you check a column but not the row.  Also I'm pretty sure your checkDiagonal only check one diagonal but not the other.

Comment: @markspace i have added a method to checkRow and i have tested the checkDiagonal but also the same result